# How to check if any element of an array is greater than 100?

Tags: ruby

This should return `true`

```
array = [30, 40, 50, 100]
```

This should return `false`:

```
array = [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Does a predefined function exist?

Comment: `array.max > 99`. Less semantic than Ursus's answer.

Comment: Why should the first example return `true`? There are no items greater than 100 in that array.

Comment: Ruby's [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html) library is full of such tools.

Answer (score 7):

Use `any?`

```
[30,40,50,100].any? { |item| item >= 100 } # => true
[10,20,30,40].any? { |item| item >= 100 } # => false
```

Note that even in your first example none of the elements is greater than 100, I took for granted you meant greater than or equals to 100

Comment: Manish, `find` and `index` with the same block also work and are similar in efficiency, though they return the logically false ("falsy") value `nil` rather than `false`, or an integer, which is a logically true ("truthy") value, rather than `true`. Logically false values are the Ruby objects `false` and `nil`. Logically true values are all other Ruby objects. `any?` reads best, however. `arr.max >= 100` works but it has the downside that it examines the entire array to find the largest value, whereas `any?` (and `find` and `index`) are finished if and when they find a value greater than `100`.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to find the first number that is greater than 100 on the array. If you are here for the same, then `find` the answers below

```
[30, 40, 50, 100, 110, 120].find { |n| n > 100 }

#=> 110
```

And if you want to find all the numbers greater than 100

```
[30, 40, 50, 100, 110, 120].find_all { |n| n > 100 }

#=> [110, 120]
```